# Cannot import BrowserRouter into index.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a new React app. This is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/main.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers:
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

As soon as I import `BrowserRouter`, I get this error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'history' in '/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/restauranteclliente/node_modules/react-router'`

I have already installed `react-router` and `react-router-dom`.

Comment: try to reinstall modules.

Comment: try to install `history` package first `npm install --save history`

Comment: @Joseph Yea! That was it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need `react-router`.. `react-router-dom` is enough to set router to your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you need to install `history` package

```
npm install --save history
```